# Jquery Get Request Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script:

```
$.get("http://www.roblox.com/catalog/", function(onWebsite) {
    console.log($(onWebsite).find(".name notranslate")[0])
});
```

For some reason, it returns undefined, although if you go to the page specified and execute: `document.getElementsByClassName('name notranslate')[0]`, it will return what I want it to. Am I using the correct syntax?

Comment: Is `notranslate` an element?

Comment: It says this on the page: (in the HTML) "class="name notranslate""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To finds the element with both "name" and "notranslate" classes. You need to write selectors together without spaces in between.

So, use

```
$(onWebsite).find(".name.notranslate")
```

instead of

```
$(onWebsite).find(".name notranslate")
```

Comment: @RobertMaron, as you are new consider accepting the answer. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)